# Pandas: use the "and" of two series in `where`

Tags: python, pandas

I have written a small function to get the log returns of a series:

```
def get_log_returns(series):
    logs = numpy.log(series.astype('float64') / series.astype('float64').shift(1))
    return logs
```

Now I would like to make sure I only include logs that are "reasonable". I know I can use `where` to exclude logs that are infinity:

```
def get_log_returns(series):
    logs = numpy.log(series.astype('float64') / series.astype('float64').shift(1))
    return logs.where(logs < numpy.inf)
```

But what if on top I wanted to exclude logs that are negative? I was hoping that something like this would work:

```
def get_log_returns(series):
    logs = numpy.log(series.astype('float64') / series.astype('float64').shift(1))
    return logs.where((logs < numpy.inf) and (logs > 0))
```

But this gives me a

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
 Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `&` operator.

```
logs[(logs < numpy.inf) & (logs > 0)]
```

`and` and `or` are not supported operations with boolean Series so you have to use the `&` and `|` operators.

Answer (score 1):

In pandas 0.13 you'll be able to do the following:

```
logs[pd.eval('0 < logs < inf')]
```

which gives a slightly nicer syntax than the current builtin Python syntax and as a bonus can be up to 5x faster for very large `Series`. With `DataFrame`s the benefit is even greater since you can actually pass query to the frame's `[]` "method" like so

```
df['a < b < c']
```

assuming a `DataFrame` `df` with columns `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Note that the reason you cannot use `and` is because of Python, not because of `numpy` or `pandas`. [Here's the PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0335/). You'll see that the status is "Rejected". It would probably be safe to assume that this PEP won't ever be implemented.

There's also [a video here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmarakana.com%2Fs%2Fpost%2F1091%2F2012_pydata_workshop_panel_with_guido_van_rossum&ei=qykJUr-FE5b94AOIl4H4DQ&usg=AFQjCNHnVonRmjSm35vJvy3lseklugijaQ&sig2=xfGI24_NpbnTGfiyCDBckw&bvm=bv.50500085,d.dmg) where at some point they talk about this.